# Youtube android app with fine speed controls

Tags: applications, youtube

I know the youtube app has the option of playing videos at 0.75x, 0.5x and some other speeds.

I am looking for an alternative youtube client that can play youtube videos at a greater range of speeds. Particularly, I need 0.9x and 0.8x

One possible solution is to download the video and play it in a native player, but this solution is too complex (for my elderly father, who wants to listen to videos with slower speed to increase comprehension) and often demands too much space on the device.

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like a request for resources, which is usually offtopic.

Comment: @NVZ Yes it's off-topic. I'm voting to close.

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575).

Answer (score 1):

There is one open-source project available, which comes with many useful features,
You can play youtube videos on any native player such as VLC.

Please check out NewPipe [NewPipe Github](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe)